# How to convert a generic or object parameter to a reference type

Tags: c#

In this scenario I can't create a base type for both TypeA and TypeB to derive from so I cannot add a Where : TypeBase on the method. I would like to see if there is another way to solve this.

```
class TypeA
{
    int number;
    string someString;
}

class TypeB
{
    int number;
    decimal someDecimal;
}

private List<int> Test(object inputs)
{
    List<int> rv = new List<int>();

    if (inputs is List<TypeA>)
        inputs = (List<TypeA>)inputs;
    else if(inputs is List<TypeB>)
        inputs = (List<TypeB>)inputs;

    foreach(item in inputs)
    {
        rv.Add(item.number);
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the type of `item` to be? What are you trying to do with each item?

Comment: @JonSkeet item would be either TypeA or TypeB, I just need to grab a common value that's shared between them. I know this can be done by using a base class or interface w/where:BaseClass but I'm curious to see if there is another way.

Comment: What are you doing differently inside the `foreach` loop for each type?

Comment: @DStanley nothing, same logic, just grabbing a value from a common property

Comment: By "common" you mean "same name"?

Comment: Can you not just have two overloads for `Test` - one for each possible list type?

Comment: I currently have 2 overloads and the code inside them is identical, that's why I wanted to see if there was a way to combine the 2

Comment: Can TypeA and TypeB be made to implement a shared interface (e.g. ICanDoLogic)?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Casting to `List<TypeA>` or `List<TypeB>` and then just storing the result back into a variable of type `object` is _useless_. The cast is only reinterpreting the reference in the first place -- it doesn't change the object itself -- and storing the result in the same variable means you still only have `object`. Why can you not do `foreach (object item in (IEnumerable)inputs)`? What are you going to do with each `item` value once you have it?

Comment: Please provide a good [mcve] showing clearly what you're trying to do, with a precise explanation of what you want that code to do.

Comment: @JustinR. In this scenario, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void GenericTest<T>(IEnumerable<T> inputs)
{
    MethodInfo property = typeof(T).GetProperty(/*YOUR PROPERTY*/).GetMethod;
    foreach (var input in inputs)
    {
        object value = property.Invoke(input, null);
        // Logic
    }
}

// To protect it from error
public void Test(IEnumerable<TypeA> inputs)
{
    GenericTest(inputs);
}

// To protect it from error
public void Test(IEnumerable<TypeB> inputs)
{
    GenericTest(inputs);
}
```

And by the way why not pass the property name to the Test method ?

Answer (score 0):

You can cast it to an `IEnumerable` and then do the `foreach`-loop :

```
private void Test(object inputs)
{
    // you can also change the parameter to IEnumerable to take advantage of compile-time type-checking.
    var items = inputs as IEnumerable;
    if (items == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("inputs");

    foreach (var item in items)
    {

    }
}
```

If the logic needs to be different for each class, use this :

```
private void Test(object inputs)
{
    var typeAs = inputs as IEnumerable<TypeA>;
    if (typeAs != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in typeAs)
        {

        }
        return;
    }
    var typeBs = inputs as IEnumerable<TypeB>;
    if (typeBs != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in typeBs)
        {

        }
        return;
    }

    throw new ArgumentException("inputs");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will do no additional work if you iterate over them independently:

```
class Program
{
    private void Test(object inputs)
    {
        if (inputs is List<TypeA>)
            loop((List<TypeA>) inputs);
        if (inputs is List<TypeB>)
            loop((List<TypeB>)inputs);
    }

    private void loop(IEnumerable<TypeA> inputs)
    {
        foreach (var input in inputs)
        {
            logic(input.i);
        }
    }

    private void loop(IEnumerable<TypeB> inputs)
    {
        foreach (var input in inputs)
        {
            logic(input.i);
        }
    }

    private void logic(int i)
    {
        // magic happens here
    }
}

class TypeA
{
    public int i;
}

class TypeB
{
    public int i;
}
```

But for the love of all that is good in the world, please don't do this.

If you really must iterate over the lists in one go for some reason, and you **know** that Test will only be called with TypeAs and TypeBs, you can handle this with a [dynamic type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var w = new TypeA {i = 8};
        var x = new TypeA {i = 16};
        var y = new TypeB {i = 32};
        var z = new TypeC(); // don't pass this to Test!
        var l = new List<dynamic> {w, x, y};
        Test(l);
    }

    private static void Test(IEnumerable<dynamic> inputs)
    {
        foreach (var input in inputs)
        {
            logic(input.i);
        }
    }

    private static void logic(int i)
    {
        // magic happens here
    }
}

class TypeA
{
    public int i;
}

class TypeB
{
    public int i;
}

class TypeC {} // no members
```

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid iterating over the lists separately? That is, what are you hoping to gain by merging them first? I'm not saying that you shouldn't, but I want to understand your use case.